# Sed with two variable

Tags: bash, sed

I encountered with behavior incomprehensible to me.

```
NODES=6
PORT=6379
until [ $NODES -eq 0 ]
do
        ((NEWPORT=PORT++))
        cp cluster-config.conf redis-$NEWPORT.conf
        sed -i -e "s/$PORT/$NEWPORT/g" redis-$NEWPORT.conf
        ((NODES--))
done
```

This doesn't work
But this works

```
NODES=6
PORT=6379
until [ $NODES -eq 0 ]
do
        ((NEWPORT=PORT++))
        cp cluster-config.conf redis-$NEWPORT.conf
        sed -i -e "s/6379/$NEWPORT/g" redis-$NEWPORT.conf
        ((NODES--))
done
```

What's the difference between

```
sed -i -e "s/$PORT/$NEWPORT/g" redis-$NEWPORT.conf
```

**vs**

```
sed -i -e "s/6379/$NEWPORT/g" redis-$NEWPORT.conf
```

Comment: `sed` doesn't have variables. You are dynamically creating a `sed` *script* using shell parameter expansion, and `sed` sees the static result of that expansion.

Comment: Also, there's no point copying the file, then using the non-standard `-i`  potion to edit it. Just use `sed -e "..." cluster-config.conf > redis-$NEWPORT.conf`.

Comment: Also, `for((NEWPORT=PORT; NEWPORT < PORT+NODES; NEWPORT++)); do` would be a much simpler loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do a `PORT++`, which makes `PORT` to be increased by one.

By the time you use `sed`, it's expanded for 6380, and then it's not found in the file.

Answer (score 2):

You want to create 6 copies of a configuration file, with the existing port 6379 replaced with one of 6380-6385. That's much more simply written as

```
port=6379
nodes=6
for ((newport=port+1; newport <= port + nodes; newport++)); do
  sed -e "s/$port/$newport/g" cluster-config.conf > redis-$newport.conf
done
```